# Inferring the modulus of continuity

Tags: real-analysis, mg.metric-geometry, metric-spaces

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$, $g:Y\rightarrow Z$ be uniformly continuous functions between metric spaces $X,Y,Z$ with moduli of continuity $\omega_f$ and $\omega_g$, respectively.  Suppose that we know that $g\circ f$ has modulus of continuity $\omega$ then can we express $\omega_g$ as a functions of $\omega$ and of $\omega_f$?

I was thinking: Since $\omega = \omega_g\circ \omega_f$ then
$$
\omega_g = \omega \circ \omega_f^{-1};
$$
where $\omega_f^{-1}$ is a right-inverse of $\omega_f$.  However, can we guarantee that such a right-inverse exists?

In the case where $\omega_f(x)=K|x|$ then can we at-least say that $\omega_g(x)\leq \max\{1,K^{-1}\}\omega(x)$?

Comment: you probably mean $g:Y\to Z$. In any case, there is not such a relation, even for invertible linear maps. Just think of a $2\times 2$ diagonal matrix $f=\text{diag}(a,b)$, $g=f^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand\om\omega\newcommand\R{\mathbb R}$In general, even the inequality
$$\om_g\le\om\circ\om_f^{-1}\tag{0}$$
will not hold, for the right inverse $\om_f^{-1}$ of $\om_f$ defined by
$$\om_f^{-1}(u):=\inf\{t\in\R\colon\om_f(t)\ge u\}\tag{1}$$
for real $u\ge0$.
Indeed, suppose e.g. that $X=\{0\}\cup(1,3/2]$, $Y=Z=\R$, $f(x)\equiv x$, and $g(y)\equiv y$. Then $\om_f(1)=1/2$ and $\om_f(u)\ge1$ for $u>1$, whence $\om_f^{-1}(1)=1$ and
$$\om_g(1)=1\not\le1/2=\om_f(1)=\om_f(\om_f^{-1}(1))=\om_g(\om_f(\om_f^{-1}(1)))=\om(\om_f^{-1}(1))=(\om\circ\om_f^{-1})(1).$$

---

However, if $\om_f$ is right-continuous, then, by (1), for all real $u\ge0$ we have $\om_f^{-1}(u)=\min\{t\in\R\colon\om_f(t)\ge u\}$ and hence
$\om_f(\om_f^{-1}(u))\ge u$, which implies
$$\om_g(u)\le \om_g(\om_f(\om_f^{-1}(u)))=\om(\om_f^{-1}(u))),$$
so that (0) holds.

In particular, if $\om_f(t)\equiv Kt$ for real $t\ge0$, then $\om_f^{-1}(u)=u/K$ for all real $u\ge0$ and hence $\om_g(u)\le\om(u/K)$ for real $u\ge0$.

Comment: This is a very clear answer!  Thank you Iosif.